# Getting just the current directory without the full path in python

Tags: python, os.path

I apologize if this is a question that has already been resolved. I want to get the current directory when running a Python script or within Python. The following will return the full path including the current directory:

```
os.getcwd()
```

I can also get the path all the way up to the current directory:

```
os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
```

Using `os.path.split` will return the same thing as the above, plus the current folder, but then I end up with an object I want:

```
(thing_I_dont_want, thing_I_want) = os.path.split(os.getcwd())
```

Is there a way I can get just the thing I want, the current folder, without creating any objects I don't want around? Alternately, is there something I can put in place of the variable `thing_I_dont_want`that will prevent it from being created (e.g. `(*, thing_I_want)`)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this:

```
os.path.split(os.getcwd())[1]
```

Although `os.path.split` returns a tuple, you don't need to unpack it. You can simply select the item that you need and ignore the one that you don't need.

Comment: I don't know why that didn't occur to me before. I knew there was a simple solution. Time for more coffee.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`os.path.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.split):

```
>>> os.path.split(os.getcwd())
('/home/user', 'py')
>>> os.path.split(os.getcwd())[-1]
'py'
```

help on `os.path.split`:

```
>>> print os.path.split.__doc__
Split a pathname.  Returns tuple "(head, tail)" where "tail" is
    everything after the final slash.  Either part may be empty.
```

Comment: Well yes, that does return the object ('py' in your example) that I'm looking for, but also returns the rest of the path. Edit - adding the [-1] works.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think rigidly specifying the split character like that isn't going to be as robust as using os.path.split, since os.path will behave appropriately across any platform.

Comment: @trynthink Ah! I forgot windows uses \, I'll remove that comment.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan But it's a good reference for someone who's sees this answer in future.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, though it's not safe (as all the given solutions) if the pathname ends with a `/` for some reason:

```
os.path.basename(os.getcwd())
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard pythonic way of denoting that "this is a thing I don't want" is to call it _ - as in:

```
_, thing_I_want = os.path.split(os.getcwd())
```

Note that this doesn't do anything special. The object is being created inside os.split(), and it's still being returned and given the name _ - but this does make it clear to people reading your code that you don't care about that particular element.

As well as being a signal to other people, most IDEs and code validators will understand that the variable called _ is to be ignored, and they won't do things like warn you about it never being used.